# New line within string for Haml/Ruby code

Tags: ruby, haml

I have some text with a `link_to`, say `"Hello 1 Hello 2 Hello 3"`. I need the string to be a link that looks like the following:

```
Hello 1

Hello 2

Hello 3
```

I'm working in Ruby/Haml and cannot seem to accomplish this. Any idea how? I tried concatenating `"\n"` within the string, and it does not seem to work either.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest thinking about the HTML needed to put three bits of text onto three separate lines. You could use <p> tags or <br> tags or <div> tags (or even others if you use a bit of CSS). Perhaps something like this would work:

```
= link_to some_path do
  Hello 1
  %br
  Hello 2
  %br
  Hello 3
```

or maybe this:

```
= link_to some_path do
  %p
    Hello 1
  %p
    Hello 2
  %p
    Hello 3
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use something like:

```
= link_to "Hello 1<br>Hello 2<br>Hello 3".html_safe, url
```

Comment: Thanks! Forgot about html_safe.